# ADFS authentication for Corpnet users

Tags: azure, windows-store-apps, adfs, federation

I need ADFS authentication for Corpnet users for my Windows 8.1 app. I don't know how to get this working. I am able to authenticate via Azure but not Corpnet.

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "authenticate via Azure". Can you please provide more details on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I mean I am able to authenticate via Live Id but not via Corpnet(microsoft.com).

Answer (score -1):

This is a complex topic to explain in just a view words as your question is rather open.

Do see if this can get you going for a web application: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736227(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or for a Windows Phone App: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/16/a-sample-windows-phone-8-app-getting-tokens-from-windows-azure-ad-and-adfs/